# Wilkinson Divider with one shorted and open port

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf

I have the following setup:

[image: Wilkinson Divider]

It is my task to calculate the only value (\$S_{11}\$) of the scattering-matrix of the resulting one-port. Here is my idea on how to do that:

From the left port and through the upper path I get:
$$
1 * (-\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}) * j * 1 * j * (-\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
And from the left port through the lower path:
$$
1 * (-\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}) * (-1) * (-\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}
$$

In total I have thus a value of \$S_{11} = 1\$

My question is if this value is right? It seems too simple for a fairly complex circuit to essentially behave like it's an open circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any mathematics, you could reason thus ...

The open circuit line is λ/4 long, so it transforms its open circuit load into a short circuit at the wilky

The wilky is now shorted on both ports, so it behaves symmetrically, you can ignore its cross output ports resistor. It's λ/4 long, so what impedance will each of its lines present at its input?

Comment: So then the impedance will be infinite, therefore behaving like an open circuit?

Comment: @Schottky yes, open